# jQuery FlexSlider: Advance Carousel One Item at a Time

Tags: jquery, slideshow, carousel, flexslider

I'm trying to get a carousel working similar to the following:
- http://flexslider.woothemes.com/carousel-min-max.html

Basically I just want it to advance by one or two items at a time, rather than replacing the whole bunch of items each time the slideshow advances.

I've been playing about with min and max ranges but it seems to give quite unpredictable results and I'm not sure that's what I need exactly:

```
$('#photos-ylnm').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    itemWidth: 100,
    minItems: 10,
    maxItems: 12,
    slideshow: 1,
    animationSpeed: 350,
    slideshowSpeed: 1000
});
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong? Is this achievable with FlexSlider?

Answer (score 5):

Ah never mind I've just found out about the `move` attribute:

```
$('#photos-ylnm').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    itemWidth: 100,
    move: 1,
    slideshow: 1,
    animationSpeed: 350,
    slideshowSpeed: 1000
});
```